# ZendDebugger startup error: Extension "Zend Debugger" cannot be loaded twice

Tags: php, zend-framework, eclipse-pdt

I am getting this error thrown every time I run the PHP CLI and need some help fixing it.  This occurs either from the native PHP CLI or when I run the CLI using Eclipse PDT.

The message seems to have no effect on operation other than as an irritant.

I am using Zend Server ZSCE 5.6.0 with its WAMP.  This is on Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.  I am also using Eclipse PDT editor 3.0.2.

My searches have found no fix.

Comment: I suggest you check if you are actually loading zend debugger twice in php.ini if you haven't already done it. :) (Check which php.ini file is used with "php -i")

Comment: Yes, I verified that it loads it only once.  I have also verified that no other INI files are being processed.  Thanks.

Comment: I am going to rethink that for just a moment due to an anomally I am seeing in the system.  Either php -i or phpinfo both show php.ini in c:\windows.  It isn't there.  It is in the Zend program files.  So, it is showing me false information.  This is true even if I use the Zend manager to execute PHPInfo.  I do know that the php.ini in Zend is working as the changes I make do occur.  But, Zend is doing something here behind the scenes of which I am unaware.

Comment: Shoot, okay, I think I might have found it per your suggestion.  The working php.ini loads zenddebugger.  It also includes Zend extensions that loads debugger without the zend.  So, it is in fact loading it twice.  I didn't see that because it is using two different names.  I have to figure out which one to use but it looks like either is working in the CLI.  That's not the same on the web, though, since I am not getting the message there.  Will take some "debugging".  Still doesn't fix the issue regarding PHPinfo but...

Comment: People on this forum are amazing.  How do I mark your comment as the answer here?

Comment: I will post it as an answer instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check if you are actually loading zend debugger twice in php.ini if you haven't already done it. :) (Check which php.ini file is used with "php -i")